# In IE10, Iframe does not adjust its Precentage (%) width and height according to its parent

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

Interestingly, I have worked this example by braking in it a very small part and found out the problem.

In IE10, if an `<iframe>` is present inside a `<td>`, the height width attributes of an Iframe given in percentage doesn't pay much heed to the height width of its parent.

Like in the following example, iFrame with the id 'test' takes height width = 100%. While its parent's height is 1px. *When you run this in IE10, the frame appears to be very large in height and shows anomolous behavior*

```
<BODY id="WESWinDesktop">
<table id=WESStructure width="100%" height="100%" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="WESMainWinTitleBarCont" height="1px">this is 'td' for iframe
            <iframe  id="test" src="" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="WESMainWinMenuBar" height="20">menu bar
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="100%" >content
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="WESMainWinStatus" height="20">status bar
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</BODY>
```

I have tried the same thing by putting a `<div>` instead of a `<td>` but the behavior is the same. So I guess there is something wrong IE10 interprets width height attributes of an iframe.

Comment: I dont see why this question should be tagged with ie9 java and javascript

Comment: Well, because I am facing this issue with respect to IE10 compatibility and this piece of code runs perfectly fine in IE9. And because its styling properties I tagged Css and Javascript

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce this error in IE10, Win7.